# Is infowars a credible source for political news?

Tags: media

As a source for news, how credible is infowars?

If you think it is not credible, can you please provide an example which illustrates it being untrustworthy (i.e. provide a claim made by alex jones and a refutation?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_Jones_%28radio_host%29

Comment: Infowars is about as biased as a news source gets.

Comment: In a word, no. Alex Jones is America's leading conspiracy theorist, according to New York Magazine.

Comment: @SirJective, your comment rather belongs to the question body. Consider editing the question to explain your rationale in more details (except the rude words, of course :).

Comment: If you believe in conspiracy theories, he's very credible. :)

Comment: @bytebuster just finished editing the post. If we could make this a list of debunked alex jones theories it might serve as a great reference for people who need convincing.

Comment: @SirJective there are already plenty of sites out there for debunking alex jones. Also, anyone that believes alex jones will invariably believe anything attempting to debunk him is also a conspiracy.

Comment: @SirJective - Debunking Alex Jones' claims *in general* is off topic here.  It'd be appropriate (on a per-claim basis) on [Skeptics.SE], which is all about doing that.  Specific political-based claims would be on topic either here or there.  But nothing on the whole Stack Exchange network would be appropriate for general debunking.

Comment: Infowars could be considered a weird niche of entertainment but not news.

Comment: [If they said it on television, it must be true](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56uSDQECrRQ)

Comment: Infowars is much less credible than Fox News or CNN.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Alex Jones claims [Pepsi uses baby fetuses as flavouring](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6UiPAqwv-k).

Interpret that as you like.

Comment: Lol can you provide a source for this?

Comment: Yea he talks about it in one of his latest videos . I'll go find it and update soon

Comment: here is one example, ( 3 years ago) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6UiPAqwv-k

Comment: THAT! If he was an unbiased credible source, he'd accuse Coca-Cola too!

Comment: @user4012 pshaw. Everyone knows Coca-Cola uses agent orange for their flavoring!

Comment: @blip - Coca-Cola uses adult fetuses, as opposed to the baby fetuses that Pepsi uses.

Comment: Can I edit this post to add this? https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-fix/wp/2017/04/17/trump-called-alex-jones-amazing-joness-own-lawyer-calls-him-a-performance-artist/